# Where is the Source code of snaps?

Tags: open-source

When I download open-source snaps on Ubuntu 20.10 I cannot find their source code, even though they are free.

Can anyone tell me where their source code is?

Comment: BTW, a program being free does not necessarily mean that it is open-source and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

To see the source code of a snap (that is how it was built), you can download the snap and inspect it.

For example, say you want to read the source code of `gnome-system-monitor` snap. You can download the snap in your current directory using:

```
sudo snap download gnome-system-monitor
```

This command will download two files, `gnome-system-monitor_148.snap` and `gnome-system-monitor_148.assert` (the number represents the snap's version and it can be different than `148`).

Then, open Nautilus and go to the directory where the files are downloaded (it's the directory inside which you ran the above command). <kbd>right-click</kbd> the `.snap` file, select to open it with the Archive Manager and navigate in the `snap` directory in the Archive Manager window that opens. Finally double click the `snapcraft.yaml` and `manifest.yaml` to open them with your text editor. These files will show you how the snap package was built.

You can find some more info in this article: [How to verify the source of a Snap package](https://merlijn.sebrechts.be/blog/2020-08-17-verify-snap/)

Comment: 22.04 doesn't give me the ability to look at that `.snap` file with "Archive manager". I can still check it with `less ...` since it's just text, but it's huge (at the one I'm looking at is some 130Mb). The `apt-get source ...` command is better. Snaps are not easy to work with...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by BeastOfCaerbannog, you can download the snap file like so:

```
mkdir <name>
cd <name>
snap download <name>
```

*(Note: no need to use `sudo ...`, this is just a download in your current directory.)*

The download saves two files in your current folder: a `.assert` and a `.snap`. The filename also includes a version.

The `.snap` file contains the actual binary snap, which includes a manifest with information about the source. That file is a compressed set of files found in a SquashFS file system. To see the list of files on newer systems, you can simply do:

```
less <name>_<version>.snap
```

That way you can verify that the files of interest exist.

To actually check the files, you need to mount the file system. `mount` does require `sudo`. I'm sure there are other ways to extract the data, but I find this one easy enough:

```
mkdir <name>.snap
sudo mount <name>_<version>.snap <name>.snap -t squashfs -o loop
```

Now all the files inside `<name>.snap` are accessible like any file on your disks (well, except that they are read-only). The `manifest` and `snapcraft` can be read like so:

```
less docker.snap/snap/manifest.yaml
less docker.snap/snap/snapcraft.yaml
```

It looks like the manifest has links to the `git` specifically used by this `<name>` project. That's where you would find the source.

For example, for docker, I found these:

```
source: https://github.com/moby/moby.git
source: https://github.com/containerd/containerd.git
source: https://github.com/opencontainers/runc.git
source: https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-container-toolkit.git
source: https://github.com/NVIDIA/libnvidia-container.git
source: https://github.com/docker/libnetwork.git
source: https://github.com/krallin/tini.git
source: https://github.com/docker/cli.git
source: https://github.com/docker/buildx.git
source: https://github.com/docker/compose.git
```